# Using split DNS when devices default to DNS over HTTPS/TLS?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

Some routers don't support hairpinning, and even when they do, it can be inefficient, so split DNS is often proposed as a best practice for hosting services that should be accessible locally and remotely. But many devices these days use DNS over TLS or HTTPS by default and generally not configurable by DHCP.

1. Firefox uses DNS over HTTPS unless you mark your sites as exceptions.
2. Android uses "Private DNS" (DNS over TLS or HTTPS), which can only be globally dis/enabled.

Do you have to manually set the "Private DNS" on every device and application that uses Private DNS? Is split DNS still considered best practice?

Comment: You would manage the devices & their settings, e.g., with group policies.